# В чем проявляется метафоричность?

Tags: сравнение, метафора

Возьмем такое предложение:

> Зашло солнце, и тысяча огненных спиц вонзилась в море.

Метафоричность в том, что **спицы** сравниваются в скрытой форме с **лучами**, или в том, что **вонзается** сравнивается имплицитно с **освещается**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Мне кажется, множественное число будет звучать лучше:
*Зашло солнце, и тысяч**и** огненных спиц вонзил**и**сь в море.*

Здесь сравниваются не спицы с лучами, а наоборот – лучи со спицами. Первое предложение о солнце даёт нам это понять и представить. А глагол *вонзились* используется в своём прямом значении, так как формально описывает действие существительного *спицы*.
Если применить простое сравнение, то можно сказать так:
*Зашло солнце, и тысячи его лучей, как огненные спицы, вонзились в море.* В этом случае *вонзились* относится к лучам и используется в переносном смысле.